# ResultSet as ***String*** to Java POJO

Tags: java, json, parsing, resultset, pojo

I have the following ResultSet in **string** format. For reasons not related to my question, I can *only* have it as a String. How can I create a Java POJO from this string?

```
{
  "columnNames": [
    "cc.expiryDate",
    "cc.number"
  ],
  "values": [
    [
      1586131200000,
      "3529-2930-4919-1213"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Here is my POJO class:

```
public class CreditCard {

    private String number;
    private Date expiryDate;

    public Date getExpiryDate() {
        return this.expiryDate;
    }

    public void setExpiryDate(Date expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

I know how to do if I have a ResultSet JDBC object, I know how to do if I have a JSON `columnName: value` syntax but I cannot find how to do it having this string. I am not looking for developing an algorithm that uses reflection - I could do this. I am looking for using already existing libraries. I guess two options are: 1) Parse the string to create a ResultSet object or 2) Convert the string to JSON `colunmName: value` format. Any suggestions?

Comment: So what is the actual issue you are having? Is it because the `values` array has strings and numbers?

Comment: No. The issue I have is I don't know which library to use. I did try Jackson annotations but I get null for the values of my attributes as I think it expects a format like the following `number: "3529-2930-4919-1213"` which is not what I have here.

Comment: Jackson is pretty much the standard for java.... GSON is probably number 2

Comment: So, do you mean that Jackson will be able to handle such a format?

Comment: Post your POJO... `values` is an array, which contains arrays of objects...is that what you have?

Comment: I added the POJO. No, it is not an array of objects...

Comment: I haven't seen any library doing this, and I don't think  there will be just because this is a unique case, but I can be wrong. But I urge you to do it yourself , its not that difficult as well. You can take a Map<List<String>, List<List<String>> and iterate over them.
for eg: map.foreach((keys,value )-> { do the processing here})

Comment: If I were in your place, I would parse this as JSON, iterate over the values array and call appropriate constructor of CreditCard  (trivial if order of columns is always identical, a bit longer but also simple if the order is not known)

Comment: Yes, I've thought about this, bear in mind thought that these result sets can get quite deep and contain other complex types and that they are not always CreditCards but POJO only known at runtime. That's why I wanted to know if there is a library for doing such a thing rather than implementing a recursive algorithm that uses reflection.

Comment: So you _"can only have it as a String"_ but do you have any influence over the format of the string? This JSON is an object with two parallel arrays, which is a design smell. Parallel arrays should almost always be a single array of objects, so `[ { expiryDate: "1586131200000", number: "3529-2930-4919-1213" }, {…}, {…} ]`

Comment: That's a very good point. To be honest I thought that this is the default way to print JDBC ResultSet objects. In principle I don't have influence over the format, but if this is not a standardised format, I guess I have a good argument to gain some influence.

Comment: It's not so much a "standard", it's more that what you have, a cc-number and its expiry date are two bits of data that relate to a single _thing:_ a credit-card, so those should be kept together in an object. Then, since you have many of them, you would keep a list (array) of those objects. It's o-o design. When you get DB results you get _rows_, each row has _columns_, so the rows are the objects and the columns are the fields of the object. As it is, this question is considered off-topic because  "It's seeking recommendations for books, **software libraries**, or other off-site resources."

Comment: I just tried to write a logic to map this,  and its not tough, just around 35-40 LOC and you can do it.